# Getting page name in order to delete it

Tags: php, mysqli, get, sql-delete

I have a database that contains the page's name and id. I'm able to get the page's id but how do I get the page's name?

What I am trying to do is delete a page that is in the physical directory itself but I'm failing. I store the file names and id inside a database. I want to get the file name from the database but I'm not sure how do I use the $current_page variable to get the filename from the database.

The $current_page variable is made using:

```
$current_page = find_page_by_id($_GET["page"], false);
```

the function of the find_page_by_id is

```
function find_page_by_id($page_id, $public=true) {
      global $connection;

     $safe_page_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,
     $page_id);

      $query = "SELECT * "; 
      $query .= "FROM pages ";
      $query .= "WHERE id = {$safe_page_id} ";
      if ($public) {
         $query .= "AND visible = 1 ";  
      }
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      confirm_query($page_set);
      if($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {
      return $page;   
 } else {
     return null;
    }
 }
```

In order to delete a page, you have to go through manage page which encodes the current page's ID and then parse it to delete page. But for menu name, how do I go about doing it?

Manage page:

```
<?php if ($current_page) { ?>

<h2><?php echo 
    htmlentities($current_page["menu_name"]); ?><br /></h2>

Menu name: <?php echo 
htmlentities($current_page["menu_name"]); ?><br />

Position: <?php echo 
($current_page["position"]); ?><br />

Content:<br />
<div class="view-content">
    <?php echo 
    nl2br(htmlentities($current_page["content"])); ?>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<a href="edit_page.php?page=<?php echo
   urlencode($current_page['id']); ?>">Edit Page</a>

<br />
<br />
<a href="delete_page.php?page=<?php echo
    urlencode($current_page["id"]) ?>" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete page?')">Delete page</a>

<?php } else { ?>
<p class="welcome">Welcome to H H Lee & Associates Dental Surgery&#8217s dashboard!</p>
<p>To start navigating, please click on the "Menu" on the top left hand corner.</p>
<?php }?>
```

Delete Page:

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
 $current_page = find_page_by_id($_GET["page"], false);

 if (!$current_page) {
    //page ID missing or invalid or
    //page  cant be found in database
    redirect_to("manage_content.php");
die(); 
 }

 function find_page_by_name($page_name) {
      global $connection;

     $safe_page_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,
     $page_name);

      $query = "SELECT * "; 
      $query .= "FROM pages ";
      $query .= "WHERE menu_name = '{$safe_page_name}' ";
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $page_name = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      confirm_query($page_name);
      if($pagename = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_name)) {
      return $pagename;   
 } else {
     return null;
    }
 }

  $current_name = find_page_by_name($_GET["page"]);

 $id = $current_page["id"];
 $menuname = $current_name["menu_name"];
 echo $menuname;
 $query = "DELETE FROM pages WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  unlink($menuname.".php");
 if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
     // Success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Page deleted.";
        //redirect_to("manage_content.php");
 } else {
      // Failure
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Page deletion failed.";     
        redirect_to("manage_content.php?page={$id}");
     }
?>
```

functions:

```
function find_page_by_id($page_id, $public=true) {
      global $connection;

     $safe_page_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,
     $page_id);

      $query = "SELECT * "; 
      $query .= "FROM pages ";
      $query .= "WHERE id = {$safe_page_id} ";
      if ($public) {
         $query .= "AND visible = 1 ";  
      }
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      confirm_query($page_set);
      if($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {
      return $page;   
 } else {
     return null;
    }
 }

  function confirm_query($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) { 
      die("Database query failed: ".
    mysqli_connect_error() .
    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno(). ")"
    );
}
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean the page filename?

Comment: Yes the page filename. Server sounds abit overkill. Is there any other methods i can use? And if i were to use the $_SERVER method. How would i truncate using substr() ?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SERVER` array contains all of the information on the currently running page.

If you want to get the filename of the currently running PHP page, you can use:

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
```

This will return the absolute filepath of the current file. Keep in mind that this will include all directories leading up until that file, so you may have to use a method like `substr()` if you want to truncate the parent directory tree from the filename.